# Automate uploading csv data into a table in Hadoop

Tags: csv, hadoop

I am really quite the amateur. I am trying to automate the import of csv data into a table that resides in Hadoop. The csv file would reside in a server. I have been googling, it seems that i would have to write a shell script to upload the csv file into HDFS and then write a hive script to import the csv into the table. All the scripts can be dumped to Oozie in a workflow to automate this. Is this right? Is there a better way? Could someone point me towards the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put a file to hdfs :

```
hadoop fs -put /here/the/local/file.csv /here/the/destination/in/HDFS
```

To create a Hive table base on a csv :

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable(Field1 INT, Field2 String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'youSeparator';
```

And once you have created your table :

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'HDFS/Path/To:YourFile.csv' INTO TABLE yourTable;
```

And yes you can do it with a Oozie Workflow or in Java for example ...

Answer (score 0):

The way I have been doing it is with an sql file and a cron job. The sql consists of loading the data into a table, then doing some other operations on it as needed.

The file consists of the same sql you would input into the Hive CLI. You run it from the command line (or as a cron job) with 'hive -f '.

Hope that helps.